# Lucene not traversing through models in the index

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Here is a basic outline of my code:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Document {

  @IndexedEmbedded
  @OneToMany(cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE }, mappedBy = "owner")
  private final Set<Issue> issues = new LinkedHashSet<Issue>();
}

@Entity
public class Issue {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
  @ContainedIn
  private final Document owner;

  @IndexedEmbedded
  @OneToOne(cascade = ALL, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "name_id")
  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_issue__name_id__text_element")
  private final TextElement name = new TextElement();
}

@Entity
public class TextElement {

  @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinTable(
    name = "text_element_paragraph",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "text_element_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "paragraph_id") },
    uniqueConstraints = { 
    @UniqueConstraint(
     name = "UX_text_element_paragraph__paragraph_id", 
     columnNames = "paragraph_id"        
    )
   }
  )
  @ForeignKey(
    name = "FK_text_element_paragraph__text_element_id__text_element",
    inverseName = "FK_text_element_paragraph__paragraph_id__paragraph"
  )
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private List<Paragraph> paragraphs = new LinkedList<Paragraph>();
}

@Entity
public class Paragraph {

  @Field(name = "data", analyze = Analyze.YES)
  @Column(name = "s_data", nullable = false)
  private String data;
}
```

I thought that lucene would be indexing the data in Paragraph, but when I open Luke it shows "issues.name.id" (id comes from a class Document extends). Why isn't the data be indexed? Thanks :)

I should also note that I just removed a manual indexer from the update method in the CRUD service. Everything stopped working after that, could it be something with my configurations?

Comment: On the first glance it looks correct. Which version of Search are you using? How are you indexing and are you sure your test data actually has non null 'data'?

Comment: @Hardy For hibernate search I'm using version 4.1.1 Final. The test data should contain all non nulls. I think the real problem here is that it doesn't update the index when you update the models.

Comment: How do you create/instantiate the model? Can you show your indexing code? Does it work when you persist new entities? You are mentioning that it does not work during updates.

Comment: When I create a second Issue model, the index is updated from the first Issue model. Also, if I delete an Issue model, the index is updated. The problem is on PUT requests (updating) for the Issue model, it doesn't call on the Document model like the create and delete methods do. However, because I'm using the ContainedIn annotation it should be updated the Document automatically, right?

Comment: How do you update the model when you add a Issue? Are you updating both sides of the association? Independent of Search you will need to manage the ORM side of things properly. Search relies on events sent by ORM. Often people forget to properly update their model (aka both sides of the association) when working with One/ManyToMany. You could try debugging FullTextIndexEventListener to see whether you get notifications from ORM.

Comment: Adding the field @ContainedIn Document owner; to TextElement solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the following to TextElement I was able to get search working:

```
@ContainedIn
private Document owner
```

Answer (score -1):

I think all entities have to be annotated as `@Indexed`, otherwise `@IndexEmbedded` would not recognize entities to be indexed.

By the way: deep traversing may cause problems with re-indexing. You need to go the whole way back with `@ContainedIn`...

Comment: But I want everything to live on the Document index. I don't want separate indexes for everything.

Comment: you don't need @Indexed on each entity. Only for the main index/entity you want to search for.